# How do I align multiple equations together at different points

Tags: alignment

If I have a document as shown

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&y= 3x +2\\
&\implies x &&= 48 \\
&&= \sin{x}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

and I want to align the places with double & together and the points with & together how do I do them both at the same time?

Comment: How do I add a sketch?

Comment: It is a picture showing what you need.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood the question correctly:

Quick hack *(corrected by John Kormylo in his comment)*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&y= 3x +2\\
&\implies x = 48 \\
& \phantom{\null\implies x}= \sin{x}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&y= 3x +2\\
&\implies x &&= 48 \\
&&&= \sin{x}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That is sort of it, I would like the 48 to be next to the x though like ` $x=48$` and the `$\sin{x}$` underneath the 48

Comment: Is a quick hack like this suitable for you?

Comment: Use \phantom{\null\implies x}.  Operators need operands (or &) on both sides.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three other possibilities, with `mathtools` (which extends `amsmath`)  and `makebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 & & y & = 3x +2\\
\ArrowBetweenLines[\Downarrow] & & x &= 48 \\
& & & = \sin{x}
 \end{alignat*}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
y & = 3x +2 & & \\
\ArrowBetweenLines*[\Downarrow] x &= 48 & &\\
& = \sin{x}& &
 \end{alignat*}

\begin{align*}
y & = 3x +2\\[-0.5ex]
 &\makebox*{${}= {}$}{$ \Downarrow $}\\[-0.5ex]
x &= 48 \\
&= \sin{x}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another kind of alignment. It concerns the alignment of the symbol `=`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
y&= 3x +2 \implies\\
x &= 48 \\
&= \sin{x}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is closer but imagine that I wanted only the `$\sin{x}$` and `48` aligned together and the `$\implies$` aligned with the `$y$`